Conjugate gradient-like algorithm with multiple search directions
I am solving an $n*n$ system $Ax=b$ in CUDA where $A$ is a sparse matrix. Currently I am solving it using the conjugate gradient algorithm.
I have noticed that $Ax$ where $x$ is $n*1$ has roughly the same processing time as $AX$ where $X$ is $n*32$ - due to the sparsity pattern of $A$ (and of course the GPU architecture being suited to more parallel problems).
I was wondering if I could use this to my advantage by, for example, somehow using 32 parallel search directions to converge in fewer iterations, or perhaps deconstructing the $b$ vector into 32 vectors $b_i$ such that $\sum{b_i} = b$ and then solving $AX=B$ simultaneously using block CG, and then retrieving $x$ by summing across $X$.
Is there any literature on this kind of approach, or does anyone know how I might attack this problem?
Thank you!
